# WordPress keeps redirecting subpages without http to https homepage after switch

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https

I just updated my WordPress site to a full SSL certificate. Everything is working as expected. Only 1 issue I can't solve.

After the update I noticed the homepage is being redirected as expected but subpages are all redirected to the homepage as well.

- `http://www.example.com` is being redirected to `https://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com` is being redirected to `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com/page` is being redirected to `https://www.example.com` (I would like this to be `https://www.example.com/page`)

I am using my `.htaccess` file to get this to work. I think I am missing something.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put the HTTP to HTTPS (and canonical www) redirect in the wrong place. It should go *before* the WordPress front-controller. In fact, it should go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section to avoid any chance of it being overwritten by WordPress in future updates.

To be honest, I'm a bit surprised that redirect would actually do anything (except for requests to static resources)? (Maybe you are seeing a cached redirect, or maybe WP itself is later redirecting to the home page?)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That redirect should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect. So change `R` to `R=301` once you have confirmed it's working OK.